# Crash while running old project on iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, xcode, crash, ios11

I have code which was initially developed on Xcode 3.2. It was then later update to become compatible with ios 7. But now when I run that code with Xcode 9 GM, it run alright on any iOS 10.x device.

But crash on iOS 11 device with following error detail:

[image]

Plus: When i open this project with Xcode 9 GM, Xcode doesn't show iPhone X simulator.

Comment: in your app have .xib ? if yes than check deployment target of xib. it will be grater than 8.0 or more

Comment: @NiravKotecha Did that. It throws compile time error without that. By the way minimum build target was needed to be set to 7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some old static libraries. iOS 11 supports only 64-bit libraries.

And also you can check Deployment target of your app. Maybe it's too low (I think ios7 deployment target is not supported now).

Answer (score 1):

I think your app is running on 32-bit

> As a reminder, new iOS apps and updates submitted to the App Store must support 64-bit. Support for 32-bit apps is not available in iOS 11 and all 32-bit apps previously installed on a user’s device will not launch

[64-bit Apps on iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=06282017b)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is you exact scenario but possibilities of crash with payload could be following. Hope anyone of below all will work for you.
Please Try Following.

Disable "Enable guard Malloc" from diagnostics.

**OR**
You Can do Following:

1. delete all certificates from keychain.
2. Quit xcode
3. Delete xcode derivedData and delete all provison profiles
4. Restart mechine
5. Download latest certifcates and provison profile from Member Center
6. Click on certifcate i will install in keychain access.your key chain access should like this

**OR**

if you are using custom framworks, you need to put it inside the Embedded Binaries section located in the Xcode project under the tab Target / General.